# Sublime text big javascript object outline

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

I'm currently working with a HUGE javascript object and i'm lost when i'm on a function...
I've no information about this function (his parent, etc..)

I want to know if someone have a trick to get more information.
Outline (CTRL+R) is a good thing but too lite for this type of document.

Maybe a plugin?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ShowFunctionName](https://github.com/huyqt/ShowFunctionName). It's supposed to display the function name in the status bar. I haven't tested it, but I skimmed through the source. It looks for a particular scope, starting from the current cursor location, moving backwards. I don't know of anything off hand that goes beyond the first "function name", but I wouldn't be surprised if someone built a plugin to do that.